# How can I delay recording of statistics on omnet?

Tags: omnet++

is there a parameter to set in the .ini file to delay the recording of statistics (I use the signals with emit in my omnetpp simulation project) and to start recording only after 10 seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you are looking for is called warm-up period. In the INI file specify:

```
warmup-period = 10s
```

The manual has detailed info on the semantics: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:warmup-period